# R remove NA value from factor in split function

Tags: r

I'm using the split function to group my data.frame into three categories (C, Q or S). Now, when I execute the split function, I notice that there are now 4 lists in the variable (C, Q, S and empty string).

I expect this has to do with an NA value, or an empty string. How do I filter this correctly?
Currently, my code looks like this:

```
# Read the data from the CSV file.
train.csv <- read.csv("train.csv")

# Create some handy variables
ship.embarked <- split(train.csv, train.csv$Embarked)
ship.pclass <- split(train.csv, train.csv$Pclass)
```

`ship.embarked` returns 4 lists (C, Q S and empty string), while I expect to have 3 (C, Q and S). How do I solve this correctly?

Comment: You can check `?is.na` or `na.omit` etc

Comment: Could you give me an example? When I used `?is.na` I only got 1 list instead of the expected three.

Comment: I meant `train.csv <- train.csv[!is.na(train.csv$Embarked),]` and then do the `split`

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to do the trick for me. Still returns the same set of data, same 4 lists.

Comment: You can check the `str(train.csv)` and also look whether the `NA` is real NA or some character string.  If you have blank string `""`, then `train.csv <-  droplevels(train.csv[nzchar(as.character(train.csv$Embarked)),])`

Comment: I get this: `Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","Q","S"`

Comment: So you don't have NA, but blank strings.  One option is in the code I just posted above/

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to remove the `""`, convert to `character`, use `nzchar` to return a logical vector, subset the rows based on that and remove the unused levels with `droplevels`

```
train.csv <- droplevels(train.csv[nzchar(as.character(train.csv$Embarked)‌​),])
```

Now, we can do the `split` and there won't be any `""`